# Creating a directory in PHP based on a bunch of variables

Tags: php, variables, concatenation, mkdir

I've been trying to create a directory following a specific structure, yet nothing appears to be happening. I've approached this by defining multiple variables as follows:

```
 $rid = '/appicons/';
 $sid = '$artistid';
 $ssid = '$appid';
 $s = '/';
```

and the function I've been using runs thusly:

```
 $directory = $appid;
 if (!is_dir ($directory)) 
    { 
     mkdir($directory); 
    }
```

That works. However, I want to have the following structure in created directories: ***/appicons/$artistid/$appid/***

yet nothing really seems to work. I understand that if I were to add more variables to $directory then I'd have to use quotes around them and concatenate them (which gets confusing).

Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$directory = "/appicons/$artistid/$appid/";
if (!is_dir ($directory)) 
{
     //file mode
     $mode = 0777;
     //the third parameter set to true allows the creation of 
     //nested directories specified in the pathname.
     mkdir($directory, $mode, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had to remove the first slash in the $directory variable, though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$rid = '/appicons/';
$sid = $artistid;
$ssid = $appid;
$s = '/';

$directory = $rid . $artistid . '/' . $appid . $s;

if (!is_dir ($directory)) { 
    mkdir($directory); 
}
```

The reason your current code doesn't work is due to the fact you're trying to use a variable inside a *string literal*. A string literal in PHP is a string enclosed in single quotes (`'`). Every character in this string is treated as just a character, so any variables will just be parsed as text. Unquoting the variables so your declarations look like the following fixes your issue:

```
$rid = '/appicons/';
$sid = $artistid;
$ssid = $appid;
$s = '/';
```

This next line concatenates (joins) your variables together into a path:

```
$directory = $rid . $artistid . '/' . $appid . $s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation works like this

```
$directory = $rid.$artistid."/".$appid."/"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're assigning one variable to another, you don't need the quotes around it, so the following should be what you're looking for.

```
$rid = 'appicons';
$sid = $artistid;
$ssid = $appid;
```

and then...

```
$dir = '/' . $rid . '/' . $sid . '/' . $ssid . '/';
if (!is_dir($dir)) { 
  mkdir($dir); 
}
```